# Roots of a simple cubic equation

Tags: functions

How would I obtain the roots of the following cubic equation?

$$5 x^3 - 8 x^2 - 8 = 0$$

Since I cannot solve for a root through observation help would be great.

Comment: try 1,2,3 see what happen

Comment: Assume there is an integer root, and write $(5x-8)x^2=8.$

What values should you try ?

Answer (score 1):

The root $x=2$ is easily guessed. Afterwards, polynomial division reduces to a quadratic, yielding the two complex roots.

Otherwise, there is always [Cardano's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method)...

Comment: He did not even show any working. Seriously just tell him to figure out how to use Laplace Transform to solve his problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change it into an ODE $$5y'''-8y''-8=0$$

This is a homogeneous ODE.From here u  find  the complmentary solution $y(x)$, two of the solution will be a complex number. Then use the variation of parameters method to find the particular solution. Im sure u can take it from here. Be careful about the integrals when using variation of parameters. This is the best method to use.

$$y(t)=e^{-0.5}(cos(8.7t)+sin(8.7t)$$

Or u can try solving it using Laplace Transform. Im sure u know how to do it
Here is some examples u can look at.
http://www.math.purdue.edu/~tongliu/teaching/266/math266_F11_mid2_practice.pdf

Answer (score 0):

HINT:
In general cubic equations are solve by [Tataglia- Cardeno method.](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCUQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FCubic_function&ei=rxjvVJPrIoO5UeyHgcAK&usg=AFQjCNGi7lr9orWNBIDRoD_hgvvb2H-e1w&bvm=bv.86956481,d.d24)
Note that $x\not=0.$ Divide equation by $x^3$ and substitute $\dfrac1x=y.$ Then you have the equation $$y^3+y-\dfrac58=0$$ Find $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $$3ab=-1,\,\,\,\,\,\,\ a^3+b^3=\dfrac58.$$ Then $$y^3-3aby-(a^3+b^3)=0.$$ If you compare this equation with the identity $$(a+b)^3-3ab(a+b)-(a^3+b^3)=0$$ you can easily see that $$y=a+b$$ is a solution of your equation. Hence $$x=\dfrac{1}{a+b}$$ is a solution of the initial equation. If you know a zero of a cubic expression you can easily factor it for other two zeros.